# Как скрыть инструмены в google map?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api

Вот что получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В углах карты видны все эти инструменты. Как их скрыть через google map API
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как говорится в документации гугл на эту тему можно сделать так, при инициализации карты:

```
function initMap() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: {lat: -33, lng: 151},
      disableDefaultUI: true  /* тут отключаются все инструменты разом */
   });
}
```

для каждого отдельного инструмента тоже есть свои поля в обьекте опций гугл карты:

```
{
  zoomControl: boolean,
  mapTypeControl: boolean,
  scaleControl: boolean,
  streetViewControl: boolean,
  rotateControl: boolean,
  fullscreenControl: boolean
}
```

подробнее обо всем этом можно почитать здесь: [гугл-мапс инструменты](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls)